# How do I Combine SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql

Attempted to import SQL file into phpmyadmin and this happenend...
I am complete newb

SQL query:

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `fe`
INSERT INTO  `fe` (  `ID` ,  `userID` ,  `type` ,  `ip` ,  `note` )  
VALUES ( 31, 114,  'e',  '75.**.***.92',  'test' ) , --
```

Table structure for table `gateway`

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `gateway` (

  `email` VARCHAR( 1024 ) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET =
 latin1;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
     near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gateway` (   `email` varchar(1024)
     NOT NULL ) ENGINE' at line 7

Comment: Where is the file you tried to import?

Comment: did you paste a dump file into phpmyadmin or something?

Comment: If you pasted those together, you need a `;`, not a `,` to separate queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  gateway (

        email VARCHAR( 1024 ) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULTCHARSET = latin1;
```

It looks right to me.
Tried it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10aa88

Maybe its with your MySQL version. What version are you using?

And as in the comments:

This:

```
INSERT INTO  `fe` (  `ID` ,  `userID` ,  `type` ,  `ip` ,  `note` )  
VALUES ( 31, 114,  'e',  '75.**.***.92',  'test' ) ,
```

should end with a `;` and not `,`